# Looking for examples in Tanach where a list of people changes order

Tags: tanach

For example Noach and family - entering and exiting the teiva, the listing is different after, from which we learn that marital relations were temporarily forbidden while on the teiva.
Can you share any examples that come to mind where before and after an event, or following the passage of time, the same names are listed in a different order to signify something meaningful?
Thanking you

Comment: Probably more common for the order to change than to stay the same.

Comment: Classic example is the order of the daughters of Tzelophchad.

Comment: Virtually every time the 12 tribes are listed the order is different

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.16b.18?lang=he&with=all

Comment: I appreciate all the replies!

Answer (score 2):

One example:

[Numbers 27(1)](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9955/jewish/Chapter-27.htm#v3)

> The daughters of Zelophehad the son of Hepher, the son of Gilead, the
> son of Machir, the son of Manasseh, of the families of Manasseh the
> son of Joseph, came forward, and his daughters' names were **Mahlah,
> Noah, Hoglah, Milcah, and Tirzah**.

[Numbers 36(10, 11)](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9964/jewish/Chapter-36.htm#v11)

> As the Lord had commanded Moses, so did Zelophehad's daughters do.
> **Mahlah, Tirzah, Hoglah, Milcah, and Noah** married their cousins.

Comment: AFAICT the OP isn't asking for any list that changes. Only for lists that change and therefore teach us something